# Combining 3 separate line plots into one line plot display

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

## We are looking at pattern recognitions and making different variables

```
unusualsubjects <- rtaverages$subject_id[rtaverages$count < 5] # make a list of subjects without enough data.
rtaverages <- filter(rtaverages,!(subject_id %in% unusualsubjects)) # only include data from good subjects.  ! = not.  Put data from acceptable subjects right back in the same data frame
# Another example of filtering subjects: let's say we only wanted to analyze subjects with accuracies over 95%
accurateSubjects <- averages$subject_id[averages$accuracy > .95] #returns all of the subject_ids for subjects meeting an accuracy criterion 
length(accurateSubjects) # tells us how many accurate subjects there are
goodSubjectdata<-filter(data,subject_id %in% accurateSubjects) # make a new data frame that contains only the data from accurate subjects
```

## Code to conduct actual ANOVA of the Respone Times results

```
model<ezANOVA(data=Data,dv=rt,within=c(set_size,target_presence,task),wid=subject_id) # You need to fill in the XXXs with the correct variable names within the variable containing all of the correct RTs.  conduct a repeated measures ANOVA - dv = dependent variable.  within = a list of all of the within subject variables.  wid = variable that is used to group data by subject
model # show results of the ANOVA model
table1 <- tapply(X=Data$rt,INDEX=list(Data$task,Data$set_size),FUN=mean,trim=0.1)#find breakdown just of setsize and task - less broken down than the above tapply code, obtained just by deleting one item from the INDEX list "INDEX=list(rtaverages$target_presence,rtaverages$set_size,rtaverages$task)" above
table1 #show means so that one can begin to interpret the data.  You'll break down rtaverages in different ways to get the different mean RTs that you need for your report

par(mar = c(4,4,4,0),mfrow=c(1, 2) ) # mfrow=c(1,2) creates two plots side by side
lineplot.CI(data=filter(rtaverages,task=="conjunctive"),x.factor=set_size,group=target_presence,x.cont=TRUE,response=rt,ylim=c(0,4000),x.leg=2,xlab="Conjunctive Set Size",ylab="RT") # produces a line graph with confidence intervals    
lineplot.CI(data=filter(rtaverages,task=="disjunctive"),x.factor=set_size,group=target_presence,x.cont=TRUE,response=rt,ylim=c(0,4000),x.leg=2,xlab="Disjunctive Set Size",ylab="RT") # produces a line graph with confidence intervals
```

Currently attempting to put 3 lines onto one plot the following way:

```
# The next bit of code is to reproduce Treisman and Gelade's Figure 1, including best lines of fit

rtaverages$set_size_num<-sizes[rtaverages$set_size] # added a new column to rtaverage data frame which is the numeric/continuous version of the nominal/categorical set_size factor which will be useful for predicting RT from set_size 
bySetSize<-group_by(rtaverages,set_size_num,task,target_presence) #collapse even more, so all subjects' data are combined together
collapsed<-summarize(bySetSize,rt=mean(rt,trim=0.1)) # make RT summary
collapsed # show what collapsed data look like.  Note that there are now only 4 (set sizes) X 2 (tasks) X 2 (present/absent trials)=16 rows

cp<-filter(collapsed,task=="conjunctive" & target_presence=="present") # plot each of the four lines separated, filtering by the right type each time
cpf<-lm(data=cp,rt ~ set_size_num) # use a linear model to predict RT from set size. Use this to get out best fitting slope (estimate for set size) and intercept
summary(cpf) # make a summary of the linear regression model. cpf stands for: conjunctive, present fit

cp3<-filter(collapsed,task=="conjunctive" & target_presence=="absent")
caf<-lm(data=cp3,rt ~ set_size_num) 
summary(caf) 

cp1<-filter(collapsed,task=="disjunctive" & target_presence=="present")
dpf<-lm(data=cp1,rt ~ set_size_num)
summary(dpf) 

cp2<-filter(collapsed,task=="disjunctive" & target_presence=="absent") 
daf<-lm(data=cp2,rt ~ set_size_num)
summary(daf) 

plot(cp$set_size_num,cp$rt,ylim=c(0,4000),xlim=c(0,30),pch=19,col="green",xlab="Set Size",ylab="Response Time (msec.)") # use a big enough range to capture all of the data
abline(cpf, col="green") # add the line with the slope and intercept derived from linear model
lines(cp$set_size_num,cp3$rt,col="green")
abline(caf, col="green") 
lines(cp1$set_size_num,cp1$rt,col="red")
abline(dpf, col="red") 
lines(cp2$set_size_num,cp2$rt,col="red") 
abline(daf, col="red")
legend(x=0,y=4000,pch=c(19,1,19,1),col=c("green","green","red","red"),cex=0.7,legend=c("Conjunctive present","Conjunctive absent","Disjunctive present","Disjunctive absent")) #Legend only should be plotted once, pch sets 4 symbols, and col sets 4 colors.  cex < 1 so that legend box isn't too big
```

I got them to combine, but now the lines lost their format:

[image: plot]

Comment: Select and ctrl+k to format as code.

Comment: Could you post `dput(sizes)` and `dput(rtaverages)` of your data if it isn't large datasets? Or give us some indication of what kind of data we are working with? Further, typically I would perform all data manipulation then perform any plotting. Currently you are plotting the legend 4 times, which is redundant but is easily overlooked when plotting occurs inside data manipulation.

Comment: Additionally in the `lines` function you call limits (`xlim` and `ylim`) which are defined by plot and are redundant. You also call `pch` which is the point character (I think?), regardless it defines the symbol of a point and has no impact on lines. I've pushed an edit to attempt to make your code more succinct as I don't feel it's a true answer, but may allow us to better answer your question.

Comment: @Badger we are looking at pattern recognition data

Comment: Yup, your question was how to get them onto one plot, it appears that was achieved by rearranging your code. Not sure what formatting you were concerned about. Can you provide an example of what you want it to look like?

Comment: @Badger I am having trouble getting the dots to show up on all the lines, as the legend says

Comment: That's likely my fault from taking out the pch in the `lines` function. Try adding that back in